# Need suggestions for testing a pencil drawing feature

Tags: manual-testing

We are working on a pencil draw feature that serves as an assisting tool for an online quiz software.

Basically you can think of it as a pencil and a sheet of paper in real life. You can use this pencil and this sheet of paper to assist you during an exam.

Any testing ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the outline of test scenarios you can verify for the pencil feature.

1. Check the pencil is selectable/deselectable from the menu.
2. Check  the text written with the pencil is legible.
3. Verify that the writing with the pencil is smooth enough to handle.
4. Verify the darkness of the text written by pencil is as per the requirements.
5. Verify that the text written by pencil can be erased by the eraser tool from the menu.
6. Verify that the quality and strength of the pencil's wood.
7. Check whether the pencil can move in all directions. For example, drawing vertical/horizontal lines/dots/zigzag lines/different shapes.
8. Verify  the robustness of the pencil tool is as per the specification.
9. Verify the total length of text written by a complete pencil.
10. Verify that the pencil writes on the normally specified surfaces clearly.
11. Verify the pencil can write in different color shades.
12. Check the pencil able to select the checkbox/radio button/dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually a number of ways you can test it:

- Core functionalities: drawing weight (thickness), is it erasable (in your pencil-paper analogy, there is normally an eraser), colour management (how many different colours there are), can you draw anywhere (it may be a good idea to limit where a user can draw on an online exam), can it resize based on the size of the browser window it is in (I am assuming you are using a browser window to facilitate an online exam)
- Additional functionalities: can you draw shapes as well as typing text, can you re-position your drawing, mobile device support (on a mobile device, browser has a very different behaviour), can drawing be retained (navigate away and back, is drawing still there?)

Answer (score 1):

Besides checking all the basic functionalities of the pencil, you should test the sheet (or screen) where a user will draw.

- Check after drawing, a new sheet can be open for a new drawing.
- Test if the color of the sheet (that means the background color of the drawing) can be changed as well as the color of the pencil.
- Check if the drawing can be saved in the desktop or device.
- Also, check whether an existing drawing can be opened and edited through the tool.
- Check if there is a function of resetting the drawing so that the user can draw again from the scratch. Because if the drawing is large, it will take a lot of time to erase the drawing.
- Test the eraser can be resizable. Use small eraser for erasing small scale drawing and the large one for erasing big scale drawing. If the eraser size is fixed and it's small, it'll take more time to erase something large in the drawing.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking for the Test Cases the engineer should think broad on different parameters. Creation of test cases is the part of [functional testing services:](https://www.qasource.com/software-testing-company)

1. The basic functionality
2. Boundary conditions
3. Stress conditions
4. Usability
5. security/safety

Further the engineer can make N number of cases there are few of them mentioned below:

1. Verify that the text written with pencil is readable
2. Verify that the writing with pencil is smooth
3. Verify that the darkness, colour of the text written by pencil is as per the its requirements
4. Verify that the text written by pencil can be erased
5. Verify the shape of the pencil
6. Verify the drawing save feature